# How often should a WSUS server be rebooted?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus, reboot

I've not been able to find info on this one. All my searches come up with info on rebooting the servers or computers that get their updates from the WSUS server, but not rebooting the WSUS server itself.

I'm just trying to figure out what would be best practice so that I can set this up in the best way. I'm still fairly new to being the Server Admin where I am and the person who did this before me never rebooted anything.

Comment: How often should a Windows server be rebooted?

Comment: More frequent than “never” and potentially less frequently than “after every patch applied” - More interesting is the question if you patch your WSUS server before or rather after the systems that depend on it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure there's an official rule, but the WSUS server should also reboot after it downloads and installs patches, even if it downloads those patches from itself.

Comment: I ended up rebooting it. I'm going to set it on a schedule for a monthly reboot. Thanks for the help!